# R configure file error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: software-installation, compiling, aix, r

I am trying to install R 3.3.1 on AIX 6.1 server.
I am getting below error.

> checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/opt/R-3.3.1':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

I tried to look out but no luck.
My config.log looks like this.

> This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
>   running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.
>
> It was created by R configure 3.3.1, which was
>   generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was
>
> $ ./configure --with-readline=no
>
> ### --------- ##
>
> ### Platform. ##
>
> ### --------- ##
>
> hostname = dwaraka
>   uname -m = 00F62E694C00
>   uname -r = 1
>   uname -s = AIX
>   uname -v = 6
>
> /usr/bin/uname -p = powerpc
>   /bin/uname -X     = unknown
>
> /bin/arch              = unknown
>   /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
>   /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
>   /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
>   /bin/machine           = unknown
>   /usr/bin/oslevel       = 6.1.0.0
>   /bin/universe          = unknown
>
> PATH: /usr/bin
>   PATH: /etc
>   PATH: /usr/sbin
>   PATH: /usr/ucb
>   PATH: /usr/bin/X11
>   PATH: /sbin
>   PATH: /usr/java5/jre/bin
>   PATH: /usr/java5/bin
>   PATH: /opt/CA/SharedComponents/bin
>   PATH: /opt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/cam/bin
>   PATH: /opt/CA/SharedComponents/SystemsPerformanceLiteAgent/bin
>   PATH: /opt/CA/uxauth/bin
>   PATH: /opt/freeware/bin
>
> ### ----------- ##
>
> ### Core tests. ##
>
> ### ----------- ##
>
> configure:3562: checking build system type
>   configure:3576: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.9.0
>   configure:3596: checking host system type
>   configure:3609: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.9.0
>   configure:4307: checking for pwd
>   configure:4325: found /usr/bin/pwd
>   configure:4338: result: /usr/bin/pwd
>   configure:4346: checking whether builddir is srcdir
>   configure:4354: result: yes
>   configure:4359: checking for working aclocal
>   configure:4367: result: missing
>   configure:4372: checking for working autoconf
>   configure:4380: result: missing
>   configure:4385: checking for working automake
>   configure:4393: result: missing
>   configure:4398: checking for working autoheader
>   configure:4406: result: missing
>   configure:4411: checking whether ln -s works
>   configure:4415: result: yes
>   configure:4426: checking for bison
>   configure:4456: result: no
>   configure:4426: checking for byacc
>   configure:4456: result: no
>   configure:4469: checking for ar
>   configure:4496: result: ar -X64
>   configure:4524: checking for a BSD-compatible install
>   configure:4592: result: tools/install-sh -c
>   configure:4627: checking for sed
>   configure:4646: found /usr/bin/sed
>   configure:4658: result: /usr/bin/sed
>   configure:4676: checking for which
>   configure:4694: found /usr/bin/which
>   configure:4706: result: /usr/bin/which
>   configure:4726: checking for less
>   configure:4759: result: no
>   configure:4726: checking for more
>   configure:4744: found /usr/bin/more
>   configure:4756: result: /usr/bin/more
>   configure:4779: checking for gtar
>   configure:4812: result: no
>   configure:4779: checking for gnutar
>   configure:4812: result: no
>   configure:4779: checking for tar
>   configure:4797: found /usr/bin/tar
>   configure:4809: result: /usr/bin/tar
>   configure:4831: checking for tex
>   configure:4864: result: no
>   configure:4876: checking for pdftex
>   configure:4909: result: no
>   configure:4919: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
>   configure:4926: checking for pdflatex
>   configure:4959: result: no
>   configure:4969: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
>   configure:4976: checking for makeindex
>   configure:5009: result: no
>   configure:5021: checking for texi2any
>   configure:5054: result: no
>   configure:5143: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
>   configure:5154: checking for texi2dvi
>   configure:5187: result: no
>   configure:5204: checking for kpsewhich
>   configure:5237: result: no
>   configure:5246: checking for latex inconsolata package
>   configure:5279: checking for unzip
>   configure:5312: result: no
>   configure:5325: checking for zip
>   configure:5358: result: no
>   configure:5371: checking for gzip
>   configure:5389: found /usr/bin/gzip
>   configure:5401: result: /usr/bin/gzip
>   configure:5417: checking for bzip2
>   configure:5435: found /usr/bin/bzip2
>   configure:5447: result: /usr/bin/bzip2
>   configure:5465: checking for firefox
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for mozilla
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for galeon
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for opera
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for xdg-open
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for kfmclient
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for gnome-moz-remote
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5465: checking for open
>   configure:5498: result: no
>   configure:5509: WARNING: I could not determine a browser
>   configure:5522: checking for acroread
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for acroread4
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for xdg-open
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for evince
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for xpdf
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for gv
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for gnome-gv
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for ggv
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for okular
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for kpdf
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for open
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for gpdf
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5522: checking for kghostview
>   configure:5555: result: no
>   configure:5565: WARNING: I could not determine a PDF viewer
>   configure:5573: checking for notangle
>   configure:5604: result: false
>   configure:5615: checking for realpath
>   configure:5646: result: false
>   configure:5659: checking for pkg-config
>   configure:5693: result: no
>   configure:5750: checking for gcc
>   configure:5777: result: xlc
>   configure:6006: checking for C compiler version
>   configure:6015: xlc --version >&5
>   ./configure[6017]: xlc:  not found
>   configure:6026: $? = 127
>   configure:6015: xlc -v >&5
>   ./configure[6017]: xlc:  not found
>   configure:6026: $? = 127
>   configure:6015: xlc -V >&5
>   ./configure[6017]: xlc:  not found
>   configure:6026: $? = 127
>   configure:6015: xlc -qversion >&5
>   ./configure[6017]: xlc:  not found
>   configure:6026: $? = 127
>   configure:6046: checking whether the C compiler works
>   configure:6068: xlc -qarch=auto -qcache=auto -qtune=auto -o3 -qstrict -ma -I/where/libiconv/installed/include -I/usr/lpp/X11/include/X11 -L/where/libiconv/installed/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib conftest.c  >&5
>   ./configure[6070]: xlc:  not found
>   configure:6072: $? = 127
>   configure:6110: result: no
>   configure: failed program was:
>   | /* confdefs.h */
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_NAME "R"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "R"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.1"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_STRING "R 3.3.1"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bugs.r-project.org"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.r-project.org"
>
>   | #define PACKAGE "R"
>
>   | #define VERSION "3.3.1"
>
>   | #define R_PLATFORM "powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.9.0"
>
>   | #define R_CPU "powerpc"
>
>   | #define R_VENDOR "ibm"
>
>   | #define R_OS "aix6.1.9.0"
>
>   | #define Unix 1
>
>   | #define R_ARCH ""
>
>   | /* end confdefs.h.  */
>   |
>   | int
>   | main ()
>   | {
>   |
>   |   ;
>   |   return 0;
>   | }
>   configure:6115: error: in `/opt/R-3.3.1':
>
>   configure:6117: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>
>   See`config.log' for more details

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Seem like you should install xlc or gcc compiler.

Comment: I have installed gcc 6.2.0 ..i have checked xlc is not installed..Ill install that and will try...Thanks rudimeier

Comment: You may also try `./configure CC="gcc"`.

Comment: I tried ./configure CC="gcc"

Comment: I tried ./configure CC="gcc" but now its giving
configure: error: Building R requires the 'opendir' system call

Comment: Maybe you should first focus on getting your actual compiler to compile anything just to validate it's working correctly. And for R you may want to take a look at the notes in this project: http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/aix/